# Как несколько раз вывести строки из БД в PHP на одной странице

Tags: php, sql

Я получаю запрос из БД. Там содержится несколько строк, которые я вывожу в таблицу. Мой код работает корректно, но если я в этой же странице хочу заново вывести такие же строки, то ничего не выводится. Как мне вывести строки из одно запроса несколько раз на странице?

```
echo "<table>";
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($query_result2)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo ("<td><input type=radio name='select_account' value='$row2[0]'></td><td>".$row2[0]."</td><td>".$row2[1]."</td><td>".$row2[2]."</td><td>".$row2[3]."</td>");
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

С подсказки сделал так:
Присвоил переменной резултат запроса:

```
$array = $query_result2->fetch_all();
```

и после этого можно делать вывод хоть сколько много раз:

```
    echo "<table>";
foreach ($array as  $row2) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo ("<td><input type=radio name='select_account' value='$row2[0]'></td><td>".$row2[0]."</td><td>".$row2[1]."</td><td>".$row2[2]."</td><td>".$row2[3]."</td>");
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Всем спасибо!

Comment: mysqli_fetch_row(...) на каждом шаге цикла забирает по одной строчке из полученных от запроса результатов до тех пор, пока там не останется строк совсем. Объявите до цикла массив и в качестве элементов ему присвойте эти строки. А затем сколько угодно раз перебирайте в цикле элементы массива и делайте с ними что угодно в разных частях страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Что-нибудь типа того:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($query_result2)) {
    array_push($arr, $row2);
}
```

А затем где угодно ниже перебирайте элементы этого массива так же в цикле и делайте с ними, что вам угодно.